# Service worker scope is not matching

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I have `service-worker.js` in public folder. 
When i register service worker i have to say

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('./public/csw.js')
```

But the problem is now scope of service worker is set to `http://localhost:2009/public` and i want to catch fetch request for `http://localhost:2009/`

---

If i try to change the scope of service worker

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('./public/csw.js',{scope:'/'})
```

That create error because service worker is called from file in other dir i.e `root/src/index.js` 

I am not using CRA

Comment: How about `navigator.serviceWorker.register('http://localhost:2009/public/csw.js')`?

Comment: @MihaiRăducanu That give same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Service Worker can only manage [a scope below its own path](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#path-restriction) for security reasons. You need to move csw.js to the root folder if you want it to handle all requests on the host. Alternatively, you could set an HTTP header `Service-Worker-Allowed: /` on the csw.js path (assuming your hosting allows you to do that)